# Recursive binding in WPF with templates

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

So I have a custom class that is designed to contain menu items and sub menu items formatted as such:

```
public class ApplicationMenuItem
{
    public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Tooltip { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationMenuItem> Items { get; set; }
    public EventHandler Clicked {get;set;}
    public void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Clicked!=null)
            Clicked(this, e);
    }
    public ApplicationMenuItem(string Text)
    {
        this.Text = Text;
        Items = new List<ApplicationMenuItem>();
    }
    public ApplicationMenuItem()
    {
        Items = new List<ApplicationMenuItem>();
    }

}
```

Before anybody asks why I don't inherit `Menu` or just create a `Menu` object and bind it, its because this class may be used on platforms and frameworks that don't necessarily use the `Menu` UI object, not to mention this class will drive nav menus, context menus, sidebars, toolbars etc....

My question is as you can see I have a self referencing list `Items` contained within to allow sub menus; binding the first level menu elements is easy enough, but how do I recursively bind sub elements while creating a template for its elements in WPF?

Comment: Since XAML itself doesn't have, AFAIK, any recursive constructs, recursive behaviors would have to be implemented in code-behind. Unfortunately, without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows exactly what you are trying to accomplish, it would be hard to know what the best answer here would be.

Comment: What do you mean? I posted the code above.

Comment: Please read the link I provided in my previous comment to understand what is meant by **a good, minimal, complete code example**.

Comment: I feel you didn't actually read the question. Above is my entire class as it stands. Beyond that, i.e. the binding, is what I am asking for help with... There is no other code....

Comment: You'd define a `DataTemplate` for `ApplicationMenuItem`. With template triggers, you can show regular menu content if it has no children, or instead show it as a submenu item with a dependant menu popup if it's one of those. That's recursive right there. It's just popups with `ItemsControl`s in them, but you can steal from existing menu templates: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082(v=vs.85).aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752296(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @EdPlunkett But `ICollection<ApplicationMenuItem>` is not inheriting `iCollection<MenuItem>` so binding the `.items` attribute of it directly will do nothing but show a list of `ApplicationMenuItem.ToString()` with no binding or formatting. `DataTemplate` is easy for the first layer, but I need somthing to also cover the n layers below it.

Comment: `HierarchicalDataTemplate` instead of `DataTemplate` seems to be what I want, I just can't wrap my head around it, especially since every example I can find is the same fixed depth multi typed list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a recursive XAML template using your `ApplicationMenuItem` class exactly as you defined it (except that I put it in a namespace called `Wobbles`). This is not finished, releasable code. But it demonstrates a recursive `DataTemplate`, and some bonus goodies like displaying the popup. You can add an `IsEnabled` property to your menu item class and implement it in the XAML with additional trigger that sets colors, and an additional condition in the multitrigger that drives `SubmenuPopup.IsOpen`. If you want to support horizontal separators, you could add a property `bool ApplicationMenuItem.IsSeparator` and give the template a trigger which replaces the grid content below with a horizontal line when that property is `True`.

RecursiveTemplate.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wbl="clr-namespace:Wobbles"
    >

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wbl:ApplicationMenuItem}">
        <Grid
            Name="RootGrid"
            Background="BlanchedAlmond"
            Height="Auto"
            UseLayoutRounding="True"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
            >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image
                Grid.Column="0"
                Source="{Binding Image}"
                />
            <Label
                Grid.Column="1"
                Content="{Binding Text}"
                />
            <Border
                Name="PopupGlyphBorder"
                Grid.Column="2"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Background="{Binding ElementName=RootGrid, Path=Background}"
                >
                <Path
                    Height="10"
                    Width="5"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Data="M 0,0 L 5,5 L 0,10 Z"
                    Fill="Black"
                    />
            </Border>

            <Popup
                Name="SubmenuPopup"
                PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PopupGlyphBorder}"
                Placement="Right"
                StaysOpen="True"
                >
                <Border
                    BorderBrush="DarkGoldenrod"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    >
                    <ItemsControl
                        Name="SubmenuItems"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                        />
                </Border>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="RootGrid" Property="Background" Value="Wheat" />
            </Trigger>

            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                    <Condition SourceName="SubmenuItems" Property="HasItems" Value="True" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter TargetName="SubmenuPopup" Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger>

            <Trigger SourceName="SubmenuItems" Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="PopupGlyphBorder" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            </Trigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window
    x:Class="RecursiveTemplate.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wbl="clr-namespace:Wobbles"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="350" 
    Width="525"
    >

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="RecursiveTemplate.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <wbl:TestViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ContentControl
                    Content="{Binding Menu}"
                    Width="100"
                    Height="24"
                    />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel.cs

```
namespace Wobbles
{
    public class TestViewModel
    {
        public TestViewModel()
        {
            Menu = CreateMenu();
        }

        public Wobbles.ApplicationMenuItem Menu { get; protected set; }

        protected Wobbles.ApplicationMenuItem CreateMenu()
        {
            var m = new Wobbles.ApplicationMenuItem("Menu");

            var msub = new Wobbles.ApplicationMenuItem("Submenu");
            msub.Items.Add(new Wobbles.ApplicationMenuItem("Sub Sub 1"));
            msub.Items.Add(new Wobbles.ApplicationMenuItem("Sub Sub 2"));
            //  LOL
            msub.Items.Add(msub);

            m.Items.Add(msub);

            m.Items.Add(new Wobbles.ApplicationMenuItem("Foo"));
            m.Items.Add(new Wobbles.ApplicationMenuItem("Bar"));
            m.Items.Add(new Wobbles.ApplicationMenuItem("Baz"));

            return m;
        }
    }
}
```

**Nits, Cavils, Kvetches, and a Brief Homily**

Working with XAML, I'd suggest making a practice of using `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`. If the items in the collection change after the UI is constructed, `ObservableCollection<T>` will cause the UI to update appropriately. For the same reason, you'll want `ApplicationMenuItem` to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I'd also prefer supporting an `ICommand Command` property as well as the `Click` event, and I'd further name the `Click` event `Click` in accordance with standard XAML practice.

"What Would XAML Do?" You'll pretty much never go wrong if you do your utmost to write code that could be mistaken for the standard library that shipped with the environment you're working in.

Comment: Awesome, It didn't occur to me that I could assign a template and by that assign it to sub items as-well making it recursive! My main list is in an observable collection, it didn't occur to me that the sub items should be as-well. Thanks for the extremely thorough answer.

Comment: No prob. BTW I just fixed a couple of things in the template: The bindings for `Image.Source` and  `Popup.PlacementTarget` were both broken, and I'd forgotten `UseLayoutRounding` and `SnapsToDevicePixels` on RootGrid